# Average within a range excluding lowest two values

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have assigned 10 assessments in my class. The students can do all 10 but only their top 8 marks will count. I would like to use a formula that takes an average of the top 8 marks from 10 (in other words, it excludes the lowest two marks from the range).

I've tried to take an average of the top 8 marks but it gives me a reading over the top 8 rows. I used:

=AVERAGE(LARGE(B2:K2,ROW(1:8)))

Where my range of data is in Row 2, Columns B - K.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So how about :

```
=(sum(b2:k2)-sum(small(b2:k2,{1,2})))/8
```

Tested and works, but if the { don't work then:

```
=(sum(b2:k2)-sum(small(b2:k2,1)+small(b2:k2,2)))/8
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, the second one worked. Now I'm going to make sure I understand this properly so that I can do it again

Answer (score 1):

In order to average top/bottom values you need to use [array formula](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/guidelines-and-examples-of-array-formulas-7d94a64e-3ff3-4686-9372-ecfd5caa57c7):

You code is correct, simply press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> to apply it as an array formula.

You formula will be surrounded by curly brackets:

```
{=AVERAGE(LARGE(B2:K2,ROW(1:8)))}
```

Comment: The largest 8 values within a range specified by B2:K2.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to enter the formula normally, you can use

```
=AVERAGE(LARGE(B2:K2,{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8}))
```

or

```
=AVERAGEIF(B2:K2,">"&SMALL(B2:K2,2))
```

or

```
=AVERAGEIF(B2:K2, ">=" & LARGE(B2:K2,8))
```